# Scrolling a UITableView cell up and then expand it

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom cells in it. The cells expands when I tap on them. I am facing an issue when I tap on the cell which is half cut by the bottom screen edge of the device. When I tap on this cell, I want cell to move up and then expand to show the details but right now it just expands and I do not know if is expanded or not. I need to manually scroll the table view up to see it.

Below is my cell tapping code. I implemented the related cell expansion methods and cell is expanding properly.

```
- (void)cartTableView:(UITableView *)iTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
    [self.temporaryCartTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:iIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
    [self expandOrCollapseCartCellAtIndex:iIndexPath];
}

- (void)expandOrCollapseCartCellAtIndex:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {

    self.selectedIndexPath = iIndexPath;
    [self.temporaryCartTable beginUpdates];
    [self.temporaryCartTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[iIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.temporaryCartTable endUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After expanding, call `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`, which should position your cell correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if rect of the cell you're extending (`rectForRowAtIndexPath:`) is fully within the bounds of the table view (based on `contentSize` and `contentOffset`, using `CGRectContainsRect` and if it's not - and only partially visible - then you need to scroll it to the bottom/top of the table view.

Comment: I tried by scrolling to the top but the last cell does not work well. If I tap on the last table cell that is half cut by bottom edge, it does not scroll up completely.

Comment: You need to scroll it after you expanded it. Also you need to provide different position when you scroll to the bottom.

Comment: how to know that where to scroll top or bottom

Comment: If your cell is the last one - you need to scroll to the bottom.